# Converting int to byte streams in python

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am new to python so please bear with if it sounds a novice question. I looked it up but different sources tell me different things so I decided to ask it here. And doc is not very clear.

I have an int that I want to convert to bytes.

```
#1024 should give me 0000010000000000
print bytes([1024])
[1024]
```

If I use bytes() I assume I get a list since when I print I end up getting [1024]. However if I do

```
print bytes([1024])[0] 
[
```

I get [ back. Why is this? So it does not return a list?

Is there a way to get the byte streams back given an integer? Ideally I want something as follows:

```
x = tobyte(1024)
print x[0] #should give me  0  00000000
print x[1] #should give me  8  00000100
```

I need to be able to use x[0] elsewhere in the code i.e. to be passed to base64 encode where I expect my data to be 64 bits

Comment: It's depend how you want to code your bytes (little endian or big). You want the string representation or the bytes representation ?

Comment: Note that `bytes` is just another name for the `str` type, and `str([1024])` just produces a string representing the list: `'[1024]'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the individual bytes from an integer, use `struct`:

```
individual_bytes = struct.unpack("BB", struct.pack("<H", 1024))
```

First, `"<I"` packs the integer as a 16-bit value, using little-endian ordering. Then `"BB"` unpacks the byte string into two separate 8-bit values.

Comment: You certainly did the better job decrypting this question. :)

Comment: Thanks chepner. Since my data is supposed to be 64 bits is there a way to unpack it without specifying 8 Bs (for cleaniliness reasons)? i.e. struct.unpack("BBBBBBBB", struct.pack("<L", 1024))

Comment: `struct.unpack("8B", struct.pack("<L", 1024))` will unpack into an 8 byte array.